# Responsive Stepper with only CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a responsive stepper that support any numbers. I tried this (refer to snippet below).

Somehow 4 is the desired amount to fit in this script, anything more or less than 4 it will all get messed up.

Refer to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z35rpbox/) to see with only 3 steps. Does anyone know how to fix this? I need help. Thanks in advance!

```css
#stepProgressBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.step {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.step-text {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.bullet {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 500ms;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.bullet.completed {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
}

.bullet.completed::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  width: calc(133% - 21px);
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 7px;  
}


/* Base styles and helper stuff */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 250ms background-color;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

button:disabled:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="stepProgressBar">
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Super Duper Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet completed">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Long Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet completed">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Loooong Title</p>
      <div class="bullet completed">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Loooong Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the question? All you've said is that you are able to do something with 4 -- no more -- no less... 4 of what? 4 colly birds?

Comment: 4 steps. i am trying to do a stepper progress bar with steps in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For three items, you need to change `.bullet.completed::after` `width` to `calc(200% - 21px);`. Change the class of the parent according to the number of items: https://jsfiddle.net/bortao/buw28o53/

Comment: but it won't work if it's 4, 5, 6 if you change width to calc(200% - 21px);

Comment: updated. for each number you need to calculate the width

Comment: thank you so much! it works like a charm! have a great day ahead!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you expect still...so I made a 4 step whatchamacallit out of `<label>`s and hidden checkboxes. Click them in a forward direction and they change. If you go backwards, you'll need to do it in order. That behavior was made so there wouldn't be any gaps.

This pure CSS dynamic behavior is possible by the following:

- [General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)
- [Label Tag `[for]` Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for)
- [`:checked` CSS Pseudo-class](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/)
- [`justify-content: space-between;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#Values)

---

#### Demo

```css
:root,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  font: 400 5vw/1 Consolas, monospace;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 30px 0 -30px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 5vw;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% - 1px), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) calc(50%), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% + 1px));
}

.s {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

#s1 {
  align-self: start;
  order: 4;
}

#s2 {
  order: 3;
}

#s3 {
  order: 2;
}

#s4 {
  align-self: end;
  order: 1;
}

.c {
  display: none;
}

.c:checked~.s {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.c,
.s {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class='box'>
    <input id='c1' class='c' type='checkbox'>
    <label id='s1' class='s' for='c1'>4</label>
    <input id='c2' class='c' type='checkbox'>
    <label id='s2' class='s' for='c2'>3</label>
    <input id='c3' class='c' type='checkbox'>
    <label id='s3' class='s' for='c3'>2</label>
    <input id='c4' class='c' type='checkbox'>
    <label id='s4' class='s' for='c4'>1</label>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: That's hella clever.